# Eclipse - List all the classes with their methods

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java project (in fact, an Android project), and I need to print in a file all the classes and methods that I have in this project.

I've been looking over the web and found the javap tool, which is interested but I don't know how to use it recursively in order to parse all the .java files that I have.
Or maybe another tool exists?

Comment: Parsing the Java files is unnecessary and complicated - use the generated class instead which can be loaded and then get the info via reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What format do you need of this output file?

Eclipse can export the javadoc for your project. These html files will contain all of the classes and their methods.

I believe you can also specify a 'custom doclet' which will allow you to customize the output.

Comment: Well, I know about the javadoc, thats what I wanted to do first. But a simple text document would be nice.

Comment: @hico, you should check out the following article. It has an example of a custom doclet that prints info to standard out. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html

Comment: Thanks.
But I do not need the javadoc. I only need class names and methods, not class members and so on.
The output format doesn't matter. It can be text, html...

Comment: Javadoc was enough for my needs, with correct settings, thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode:

1. Generate a list of files in the `bin` folder of your project. If you don't know how, use `FileUtils` from [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/).
2. Make sure the file name ends with `.class`
3. Remove "bin/" from the path. The resulting string is the name of the class with `/` instead of `.`. Replace it with `.`
4. Load the class with `Class.forName()`
5. Use the [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/index.html) to get the names of all fields and methods.